# Confused about the time frame

Tags: dragon-ball-z

In Dragonball Z, the Saiyans send baby Goku to Earth moments before Frieza destroys the planet Vegeta.  Although the movie Bardock, father of Goku is a movie and should exist in the movieverse, it is official canon for the show as well.  At the start of DBZ, Raditz tells Goku that the planet Vegeta was destroyed three(3) years ago, yet Goku is in his mid 20's when Raditz arrives.  How could Vegeta have been destroyed only three years ago when Frieza destroys it right after Goku is sent off planet?  Is this just a continuity error?

Comment: Maybe years is subjective. An earth year is shorter than a Pluto year

Comment: @cde, that's what I mean.  What's it subjective to?  Is it three Earth years?  Are the planet Vegeta's years that much longer so it's only been three of Vegeta's years since it was destroyed?

Comment: Note that (from my rough calculations) it's not implausible for Planet Vegeta to have an orbital period of between 6 and 7 Earth years and still remain within the habitable zone of its star. The star would likely have to be somewhat brighter than our own, but not infeasibly so. (But then, I'm not an astrophysicist.)

Comment: Yea, let's not dwell on real science on dragon Ball, it will be as one sided beat down as the rest of the shows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragonball is an anime based on a manga source that was still being written as the show aired. The definitive source is the manga or works with writing credit given to Toriyama. (the creator of the series)

[Bardock: The Father of Goku](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Ball_Z:_Bardock_-_The_Father_of_Goku) has such a writing credit.

Additionally the show corrects itself when the relevant time period occurs. Likely the 3 years figure was just written in by mistake. Normally we try to twist ourselves around on this site to make mistakes still somehow make sense, but this goof is really just the product of some writer not knowing what the future would hold.

Dragonball, and any anime based on a yet-to-be-completed Manga really, is full of little inconsistencies like this. [Here is a list of many of them.](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_inconsistencies)

Comment: Hello. Any canon source (interview or anything) saying "yeah it's just an inconsistency"

Comment: @Kalissar Not that I was able to find. That episode isn't filler either. I'm trying to find what Raditz says in Japanese or in the manga or in the more recent Kai to see if it is fixed, but I don't have any of these handy.